# VBA Code to Create Sheets based on the values in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a code to create sheets with the name in column A. I have used this code but it is not fulfulling my requirement. The code is ;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
Dim sheetCount As Integer    
Dim sheetName As String    
Dim workbookCount As Integer    

With ActiveWorkbook    
sheetCount = Sheets(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row    
For i = 2 To sheetCount Step 1    
sheetName = .Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value    
workbookCount = .Worksheets.Count    
.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(workbookCount)    
.Sheets(i).Name = sheetName    
'.Sheets(i).Range("A" & i, "F" & i).Value = .Sheets("sample").Range("A" & i, "F" & i).Value    
Next    
End With    

Worksheets(1).Activate    

End Sub
```

Upon running this code in first go, it creates sheets with the text present in column A. But the problem is when i entered new text in that column, it makes previous sheets as well. I am looking for a code which only create the sheets with the new text being entered in the column and donot make sheets which are already made. Kindly help me out on this as i tried too much but didnt find any code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, and is tested:  Note, if you try to use a name like "History" that is reserved you will get an error.  I am not aware of all the reserved names.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sheetName As String
Dim workbookCount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim match As Boolean

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    match = False
    sheetName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Text

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheetName Then
            match = True
        End If
    Next

    If match = False Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Edit: Added Screen Shots

Answer (score 0):

You can try thi function:

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean

Dim Test As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

Test = Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1").Select

If Test Then
    SheetExists = True
Else
    SheetExists = False
End If

End Function
```

Using the function this way:

```
Sub test()

If SheetExists("MySheet") Then
    MsgBox "Sheet exists"
Else
    MsgBox "Sheet is missing"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually have these two helper functions in my workbooks / personal workbook

```
Option Explicit

Function getSheetWithDefault(name As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook) As Excel.Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    If Not sheetExists(name, wb) Then
        wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)).name = name
    End If

    Set getSheetWithDefault = wb.Sheets(name)
End Function

Function sheetExists(name As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    sheetExists = False
    For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
        If sheet.name = name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sheet
End Function
```

To create the worksheets you just iterate over the sheet names and use the getSheetwithDefault function

The following code demonstrate this:

```
sub createSheets()
    dim cursor as Range: set cursor = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

    while not isEmpty(cursor)
        getSheetWithDefault(name:=cursor.value)
        set cursor = cursor.offset(RowOffset:=1)
    wend
end
```