# Add name fields to a ComboBox based on a column without repeating?

Tags: vba, excel

I found this link here: [VBA Code to Create Sheets based on the values in column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247459/vba-code-to-create-sheets-based-on-the-values-in-column-a)

It tells me how to create a list of sheets from a column, based on the names in one of the columns on the first sheet without repeating.

I've tried to translate this code to being useable for a ComboBox, but my VBA skills are most definitely lackluster.

What I have so far is

```
Private Sub form_load()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim cellName As Integer
Dim match As Boolean

lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    match = False
    cellName = .Sheets(1).Range("F" & i).Value

    For _________________

ComboBox1.AddItem i


End Sub
```

You'll notice that in the example I linked, they use the code

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheetName Then
            match = True
        End If
    Next
```

to determine if a cell has already been used as a sheet name. However, I'm not familiar enough with VBA to know whether or not a complementary command exists to check for values in a combobox.

Comment: Nope, you'll have to loop again to test and set a boolean to know if you already have it or not! Or you could use a dictionnary : http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html

Comment: do you want to place the boxes on a UserForm or just on a sheet?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman My end goal is to have this combo box be able to select an option, then apply a certain filter to ~15 pivot tables at the same time. This is the best way that I can think of to do it. If there's a better way, I'm more than open to suggestions!

Comment: @R3uK, is there a way to display all the items in a combobox's list? For that matter (this may reveal how new I am to VBA), is there an `in` function? Like, could I say `If cellName In (list of current combobox values) Then Next ELSE combobox1.additem i Next end If`

Comment: Nope, there isn't such a thing in Comboboxes! You'll have to loop on the items! There is something like this for dictionnary (`.Exists`)

Comment: Having `ComboBox1.AddItem i` will only add a number... are you sure you want that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "loop on the items." In the example I linked, it looks to me like they used the loop and boolean as your described, but I don't know how to make it apply to my situation.

Comment: @DirkReichel, you're right. I meant cellName *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim cellName As Integer
Dim match As Boolean
Dim iItem As Integer, sItem As String

lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

    match = False
    sItem = Sheets(1).Range("F" & i).Value2

    For iItem = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ComboBox1.List(iItem) = sItem Then

            match = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next iItem

    If Not match Then ComboBox1.AddItem sItem

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! I threw it on a button, and it worked like a charm. You're the man, Scott!

Comment: worst-case O(n^2) performance though. A collection works nicely: `On Error Resume Next: For each item in range: collection.Add item.value: Next: For each item in collection: ComboBox1.Add....` etc